# How can one change the Azure AD redirect URL?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-active-directory

If a user creates a new .NET web application in Visual Studio, they can specify the type of authentication. If one selects "work or school accounts" and specifies their specific Azure domain like so:
[image]

This will generate code to be able to authenticate against Azure AD

Without logging into the Azure dashboard itself, somehow Visual Studio is able to configure a login `redirectUri`. This means that behind the scenes, somehow the url "http://localhost:43999" (Or whatever port number it generates) is registered as the redirect URL after successful Azure login.

How do i change this? I have tried hardcoding it in the configureApp function as well as in the Azure dashboard [as suggested here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/troubleshoot/azure/active-directory/error-code-aadsts50011-redirect-uri-mismatch)

But even with both those things set, i get the following error:
[image]

Here is the configureAapp function:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {

        System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        

        //below code replaces above line to stop infinite redirect loop
        //https://dotnetcodetips.com/Tip/91/Azure-OWIN-website-login-gets-stuck-on-a-never-ending-redirect-loop
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            CookieManager = new SystemWebCookieManager()
        });

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(

                        new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
                        {
                            ClientId = myclientId,
                            Authority = authority,
                            PostLogoutRedirectUri = mypostLogoutRedirectUri,
                            //RedirectUri = "this doesnt work?",

                            

                            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                            {
                                AuthenticationFailed = (context) =>
                                {
                                    context.HandleResponse();
                                    context.OwinContext.Response.Redirect("/Home/auth_error");
                                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                                },
                                SecurityTokenValidated = (context) =>
                                {
                                    string name = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.Name;// context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst("preferred_username").Value;
                                    context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, name, string.Empty));
                                    return System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FromResult(0);
                                }
                            }
                        });


    }
```

Comment: Can you paste the snip of the redirectURL configured in portal?

Comment: @Rukmini i dont have access to it at the moment. But under authentication-> Redirect URI's the URL is not the localhost url i mentioned above but the actual one i need when deploying to a server

Comment: And hence you are getting the error as the URL is not registered under Azure Portal Application

Comment: @Rukmini can you please advise where it needs to be registered?

Comment: That depends of the app registration made on Azure AD. There's a redirect URI there and it should match the one defined in your application. Visual Studio will create for you the app registration in Azure and set the URIs. You can change it using Azure portal

Comment: Go to your Azure Active Directory -> App registration -> Your App -> Authentication -> Set the redirect URI

Comment: @Cid does that mean that every time i create a new application that points to the same Azure domain it will generate a new redirect url behind the scenes and store it automatically? if so, could you please point out where i can find these urls?

Comment: Rukmini already explained to you about the error message, that asked you to go to Azure portal and change redirect url in Azure AD menu. You used VS to create a new application and set an original redirect url. You can certainly change the redirect url by code but not by VS. That's using [Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#request-body) to update the application. You can see the request body and the `web` property. However it still requires you to go to Azure portal to get API consent.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error ***"AADSTS50011: The redirect URI 'xxxx' specified in the request does not match the redirect URIs configured for the application 'xxx. Make sure the redirect URI sent in the request matches one added to your application in the Azure portal."*** usually occurs if the authentication request redirect URL is not matching the redirect URLs configured in the Azure Portal.

I created an **ASP dot.net web application** and the redirect URL is automatically set localhost value:

```cs
<appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="ida:ClientId" value="ClientID" />
    <add key="ida:AADInstance" value="https://login.microsoftonline.com/" />
    <add key="ida:Domain" value="microsoft.onmicrosoft.com" />
    <add key="ida:TenantId" value="TenantID" />
    <add key="ida:PostLogoutRedirectUri" value="https://localhost:44347/signin-oidc" />
  </appSettings>
```

[image]

And the `configureAuthapp` function looks like:

```cs
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
                new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    ClientId = clientId,
                    Authority = authority,
                    PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,

                    Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
                    {
                        SecurityTokenValidated = (context) =>
                        {
                            string name = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst("preferred_username").Value;
                            context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, name, string.Empty));
                            return System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FromResult(0);
                        }
                    }
                });
                 
        }
```

[image]

Now make sure to check the redirect URI **`https://localhost:44347/signin-oidc`** has been registered in the Azure Portal:

*Go to your Azure Active Directory -> App registrations -> Your App -> Authentication -> Set the redirect URI*

[image]

***I am able to login to the Application successfully like below:***

[image]

When I modified the redirect URL in the code, I got the **same error**:

[image]

Hence, **to resolve the error** make sure that the redirect URL must match one of the redirect URLs in the Azure Portal.

- Match the redirect URI in the `configureApp` function with the redirect URI on the Azure Portal.
- **Or**, modify the `configureApp` function's redirect URI to match with the Azure Portal redirect URI.

> **As mentioned by you,** under authentication-> Redirect URI's the URL is not the localhost url I mentioned above but the actual one i need when deploying to a server

In your scenario, add the localhost redirect URL under the authentication tab of the Azure AD Application. For this you need proper permissions to login to Azure Portal and update the redirect URL such as Application Administrator.